# tcs command to convert encoding

Tags: encoding

I'm trying to use the tcs command to convert the encoding of some files, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
$ file ascii.txt
ascii.txt: ASCII text

$ tcs -f ascii -t utf ascii.txt > f2.txt

$ file f2.txt
f2.txt: ASCII text
```

Any idea why the new file isn't in UTF encoding?

Comment: a) `file` uses only the initial bytes, b) Text that uses only valid ASCII characters would have the same encoding in UTF-8 and ASCII, iirc.\

Comment: perhaps see [can gedit create a Unicode file?](//askubuntu.com/q/769648)

Answer (score 1):

in plaintext files the encoding `file` is presenting to you depends on the content.

as long as it has no utf-8 special characters (umlauts or similar) `file` will show `ascii`, as soon as there is an `ä` for example, the enconding changes to `utf-8`.

contrary to @muru's comment I could not find a limit testing it up to 60k of text file with an `ä` at the last line.

Comment: Ok, "initial" might be an understatement, it reads about 100K.